# python - list, print

Tags: python, list, printing

I want to get "The fourth item in 'days' is: Thu

But, I don't know why it doesn't work that I want

```
def get_x(a, b):
  a[b]

days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
print("The fourth item in 'days' is:", get_x(days, 3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `get_x` returns nothing.

```
def get_x(a, b): 
    return a[b]

days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

print("The fourth item in 'days' is:", get_x(days, 3))

The fourth item in 'days' is: Thu
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make the `get_x` function return your answer.

```
def get_x(a, b):
  return a[b]

days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

print("The fourth item in 'days' is:", get_x(days, 3))
#The fourth item in 'days' is: Thu
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "return".

```
def get_x(a, b):
    return a[b]

days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

print("The fourth item in 'days' is:", get_x(days, 3))
```

Output:

```
The fourth item in 'days' is: Thu
```